# Biblatex gobbles punctuation after undefined references

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am trying to use `biblatex` with the `authoryear` style, but when I have undefined references it "gobbles" the next punctuation point.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{UNDEFINED}A

\textcite{UNDEFINED}:

\textcite{aksin}:

\end{document}
```

How can I patch `\textcite` (or the bib drivers) so that it does not gobble the punctuation?

Comment: Why the bounty? What is the problem with your own patch?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not sure, but the solution has problems with multiple citations: `\textcite{UNDEFINED,aksin}:` and `\textcite{UNDEFINED,FLUNDEF}:` give unwanted colons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Fixed in version 3.8 of `biblatex` ([#630](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/630))

I had a bit of time on my hands to investigate this.

In a `\cite`-like command the first time the citation list is processed with [`\blx@citeadd`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8945), this [happens](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8911) in [`\blx@citeloop`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8897). That command [distinguishes](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8951) citations that were found in the `.bib` file and those that weren't (i.e. are undefined). [The citations that were found are saved in a macro for further processing](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8953), [the keys of those that weren't found are written out immediately in bold](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8955). [Then the defined citations are passed](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L8924) on to [`\blx@citeprint`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L9024).
The command `\blx@postcode` that does the postpunct stuff - and a little bit more if required - [is only called in `\blx@citeprint` when the last item has been processed](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/d0e866e1ee99027bbad5d530f8bd5b14f593fb6e/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L9059).

If we have only undefined citations in our cite command, we never call `\blx@postcode` since the chain of macros is only executed with the list of defined citations, and not at all if this list  is empty.

So we need to make `\blx@citeloop` call `\blx@postcode`  directly in case there are no defined citations. It turns out that due to the nature of the additional code that `\blx@postcode` might contain it is not safe to execute there. We need to save the postpunct in a new command and use that instead.

My solution is to split the postpunct part from `\blx@postcode` into a new `\blx@postpunct@saved` (sadly the name `\blx@postpunct` was already taken, but suggestions for a better name are gladly accepted). This new macro can then be called in `\blx@citeloop` if there are no defined citations and otherwise together with `\blx@postcode` in `\blx@citeprint`.

The necessary modifications are not very copious, but the nature of the changed macros does not allow for a short MWE. The necessary changes can be found in the pull request https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/630; it has been merged and the fix is included in `biblatex` v3.8.

Now

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style = authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{UNDEFINED}A

\textcite{fghgvjh}:

\textcite{UNDEFINED}:

\textcite{aksin}:

\textcite{UNDEFINED,aksin}:

\cite{UNDEFINED,aksin}.

\textcite{aksin,UNDEFINED,gundf}:

\textcite{UNDEFINED,FLUNDF}A

\textcite{UNDEFINED,FLUNDF}:

\textcite{aksin,sigfridsson}:

\cite[14]{UNDEFINED,aksin}:

\cite[14]{UNDEFINED,aksin}A

\end{document}
```

gives

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Wow, nice hunting. I never would have been able to rip it apart and get it back together without have a few broken pieces and a few things left over. I need a bit of time to pull your file and test it out, but your results look promising.

Comment: @StrongBad Note that you can't simply download the `biblatex.sty` from my github and use it as a drop-in replacement of `biblatex.sty`. You will have to use the development version of Biber (3.8, from sourceforge) and you will have to use the install script.

Comment: @StrongBad https://gist.github.com/moewew/373b55c9b1ca2676d1ecf2f6f7c81268/revisions is a drop-in replacement for `biblatex` 3.7's `biblatex.sty`.

Comment: You rock. Was just locking at how to make a diff that I could use on my version.

Comment: @StrongBad I see you have awarded the bounty, thank you. Does that mean that you could test the solution and are happy with it? If so -- and even more so if not -- I'd really appreciate a short heads up because I'm thinking of opening a pull request to get this into the next release of `biblatex`. Real-life testing/feedback would be appreciated before merging.

Comment: Yes, it works great.

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for the feedback! You can follow the progress of the PR at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/630

Answer (score 3):

What I decided on in the end is to patch `\blx@citeadd`. I am not sure if this is the best macro to patch. It seems the "gobbled" punctuation is kept in `\abx@field@postpunct`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\blx@citeadd}{%
    \expandafter\abx@missing\expandafter{\blx@realkey}%
}{%
    \expandafter\abx@missing\expandafter{\blx@realkey}%
    \ifundef{\abx@field@postpunct}{}{\abx@field@postpunct}%
}{}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textcite{UNDEFINED}A

\textcite{UNDEFINED}:

\textcite{aksin}:

\end{document}
```